# IIS 7 configuration compare

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have 2 IIS 7 environments and the same application throws error in one server and it works fine on another. The code is exactly same but there are plenty of IIS configuration for the application, which are not documented. Is there any way, I can extract the configuration in a file (XML or similar) and compare them between the servers to see what is missing?